# How To Save Frontend Data across Website With JS?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Let's Say That I Have A Website With 4 webpages. How Can I Save User Data Across The 4 webpages? So Webpage no.1 Has access To The Same Saved Data As webpage no.2. Is it Possible To do This With No Backend And How?

Comment: Take a look on [**this**](https://bitsofco.de/an-overview-of-client-side-storage/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is Cross-Domain Messaging With postMessage and use webstorage to save the data at each website.
https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: This seams To be What I Want Thanks So Much!

Answer (score 0):

Just save It to `localstorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem('test', 1);
```

And use it:

```
console.log( localStorage.getItem('test') ); // 1
```

More about it [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).